# Does Enduring Agony increases the damage of bleeding and poison?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I know that Enduring Agony (finesse ability) increases the duration of poison and bleeding but does it increase their damage as well?

Comment: Increasing the duration *results* in an increase in damage, just not an increase in damage per second.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ok wait there is something i don't get here,when you lets say have a weapon with 10 poison damage over 5 seconds,would that mean that it deals 10 poison damage every second for 5 seconds,or does it means it deals only 10 damage through those 5 seconds?Because the game does say "10 poison damage over 5 seconds" which made me think it takes 5 seconds to deal that 10 damage,which would then mean that if you extend the duration of the poison you would actually make it weaker by increasing the time it takes to reach that damage of 10.

Comment: The games has to store damage and time separately, because they're two different stats on the random gear. Divide the damage by the time to get the damage per *tick*.  When you later increase the duration via Enduring Agony, you're effectively adding "ticks" to the DoT, not altering the underlying mechanic.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Which means that by extending the duration of poison it takes longer to deal the full damage,which actually makes it weaker,unless i missed something again in your explanation.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Nevermind i get it now,at least i think i do.Put up everything you said in your comments and post it as answer and i'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but I'll answer if only to provide one clear answer, combining all the information.

**Enduring Agony does not increase the damage per second of bleeding and poison abilities, but it does increase their duration which effectively increases their damage by extending the duration of the DPS effect.** For example, an effect of 10 poison damage over 5 seconds is a DPS of 2 damage/second for a total of 10 damage over 5 seconds, but with 1 level in Enduring Agony, the effect lasts 6 seconds (5 * 1.2 = 6), thus dealing 12 damage over 6 seconds. An additional 2 points in this example would yield 14 damage over 7 seconds, etc. It's not going to make or break the amount of damage you deal as the numbers are usually so small.

The more useful aspect is that **by increasing the poison and bleeding effect duration, the weakening of the opponent's damage dealt caused by the poison effect and the weakening of the opponent's defense by bleeding are also extended.** By extending the bleeding effect, you also extend the window to do more damage with other attacks, leading to a further improvement in damage.

Additionally **Enduring Agony also increase the damage of Shadow Flare** which, while not devastating towards the end of the game, it also causes a bleed effect and can still be marginally useful against big enemies if all 5 blades hit and can be good if you need to stun some enemies quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It only increases the duration, but it does increase the damage of Shadow Flare ([Reference](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Enduring_Agony)). It basically buffs two different attacks in one skill.

1. +20% Bleeding and Poison duration, +10% Shadow Flare Damage
2. +30% Bleeding and Poison duration, +20% Shadow Flare Damage
3. +40% Bleeding and Poison duration, +30% Shadow Flare Damage
4. +55% Bleeding and Poison duration, +40% Shadow Flare Damage
5. +70% Bleeding and Poison duration, +50% Shadow Flare Damage

Comment: I was wondering if it was a debuff that increases the duration of bleeds and poisons applied in the future or if it strictly extends the duration of currently active (previously applied) bleeds and poisons. ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it increases the status effect of poison and bleeding. Poison weakens your opponents damage and bleeding weakens their defense. So this would increase HOW LONG their stats are weakened. Its the only thing that really makes any sense.